# What's the best way to browse/search/grok a Rails namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I know there are Rails gurus out there who know exactly how to do this.  I have a very large enterprise application with many private gems which share models across projects.  The models all live in a namespace called "Applications".

Is there a way to do something like:

```
> pp MyClass.methods.sort
```

... but for namespaces?

I'd like to see all of the classes inside a particular namespace.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NM, I found Namespace.constants, and I'm off to the races! :)

```
puts Namespace.constants
```